# Kubuntu 18.04: How does Dolphin file manager sort files "naturally"?

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, file-sorting

I have the following files:

```
$ ls
_010.txt  01.txt    10.txt    1.txt  3.txt  mov001  mov00a  _mov00A  mov00B  mov01A
010.txt   _0mov00A  _1mov00A  2.txt  4.txt  mov002  mov00A  mov00aA  mov010
$
```

I used `ls -1` by itself or preceded by various `LANG=` options and the order of files is as shown below:

```
ls -1                 |                 
ls -1 LANG=en_GB.utf8 |  ls -1 LANG=C   
ls -1 LANG=en_US.utf8 |  ls -1 LC_ALL=C  
---------------------------------------
       _010.txt       |     01.txt      
       010.txt        |     010.txt     
       01.txt         |     1.txt       
       _0mov00A       |     10.txt      
       10.txt         |     2.txt       
       _1mov00A       |     3.txt       
       1.txt          |     4.txt       
       2.txt          |     _010.txt    
       3.txt          |     _0mov00A    
       4.txt          |     _1mov00A    
       mov001         |     _mov00A     
       mov002         |     mov001      
       mov00a         |     mov002      
       mov00A         |     mov00A      
       _mov00A        |     mov00B      
       mov00aA        |     mov00a      
       mov00B         |     mov00aA     
       mov010         |     mov010      
       mov01A         |     mov01A
```

But when I use the `Natural sorting` option (Dolphin Preferences > General > Sorting Mode) of Dolphin 17.12.3 which is the default version of Kubuntu 18.04, I get a different sorting order as shown in the `Name` column in the image below:

[image: Natural Sorting in Dolphin]

My question: how does Dolphin achieve this type of sorting?

The [Dolphin Handbook](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/dolphin/configuring-dolphin.html#preferences-dialog-viewmodes) doesn't have much to say:

> Sorting Mode controls how items are sorted in the view. If Natural
>   sorting is enabled, the sort order of three example files will be
>
> File1,
>
> File2,
>
> File10.
>
> If this option is disabled, the normal alphabetical sorting case
>   sensitive or case insensitive will be used, which leads to the sort
>   order
>
> File1,
>
> File10,
>
> File2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/), discusses the usefulness of natural sorting but doesn't deal with how filenames with a leading `_` are listed before other files.

The answers to [How do I make ls sort underscore characters first?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/how-do-i-make-ls-sort-underscore-characters-first) address the leading `_` issue.

A solution using [shell expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39830/61798) to bypass any sorting by `ls` has:

```
ls -lf _* [!_]*
```

So, for the files in the question,

```
ls -lf -1 _* [!_]*
```

provides the same sort result as does Dolphin's natural sort:

```
$ ls -lf -1 _* [!_]*
_010.txt
_0mov00A
_1mov00A
_mov00A
010.txt
01.txt
10.txt
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
mov001
mov002
mov00a
mov00A
mov00aA
mov00B
mov010
mov01A
$
```

I don't know if this is the exact same mechanism that Dolphin incorporates to provide natural sorting.

Answer (score 2):

"Natural sorting" detects numbers in file names and uses numerical sorting on this part of the filenames, therefore 010.txt and 10.txt come after 4.txt (10 > 4).

1 < 2 < 10, so mov001 and mov01A come before mov002 and mov010.

0 < 1 < 10, therefore _0mov00A < _1mov00A < _010.txt

etc.