# Sorting files and folders with underscore at the beginning

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, locale, ls

I use an underscore at the beginning of file and folder names to mark them as something "special". But this sorting doesn't work for the most programs under Linux. I tried `LC_COLLATE=C ls` and other locales but the results are something strange. Let's say I have these folders:

```
2
A
_F
G
K
S
x4
```

This is the sort order of `ls`. When I use `LC_COLLATE=C ls`, I have this:

```
2
A
G
K
S
_F
x4
```

I have this under Xubuntu 18.04 using the xfce-terminal-emulator on 2 machines.

What is wrong here?

Comment: How do you expect them to sort?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I think OP wants the special characters to placed first/ higher in list.

Comment: Even at that we are still guessing as OPs results could be any thing!

Comment: i want to sort the files/folders like dolphin (kde file manager) sorts them. all folder first, the all files. folders with underscore at top of al folders, the same with files with underscore at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort files with leading underscores to the end with `--sort=version` or `-v` which is equivalent to `sort -V` (natural version sort) (which is most useful for sorting files with numbers).

```
$ ls -v1
2
A
G
K
S
x4
_F
```

Details on version sorting are in `info ls`... note that:

```
‘LC_COLLATE’ is ignored, which means ‘ls -v’ and ‘sort -V’ will
 sort non-numeric prefixes as if the ‘LC_COLLATE’ locale category
 was set to ‘C’.
```

Perhaps this is adequate for your purpose.

Comment: Just to mention that Dolphin (Kubuntu's file manager) sorts them, from top to bottom, like this: _F, 2, A, G, K, S, x4. It's using something called "Natural" sorting. I have a question on it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040499/kubuntu-18-04-how-does-dolphin-file-manager-sort-files-naturally

Comment: Cleaned up my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Zanna's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103756/248158) provides one solution. Another solution is this:

```
$ ls -lfr -1 _* [!_]*
_F
2
A
G
K
S
x4
```

Comment: This shows also all sub folders and files that are stored in the folder.